# What did Adam Smith mean by "money price of labour" in "The Wealth of Nations"?

Tags: meaning, adam-smith, the-wealth-of-nations

From [Chapter V](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/3300/pg3300-images.html#chap07) of *An Inquiry into the Nature and Causes of the Wealth of Nations by Adam Smith:*

> Though the real value of a corn rent, it is to be observed,
> however, varies much less from century to century than that of a
> money rent, it varies much more from year to year. The money
> price of labour, as I shall endeavour to show hereafter, does not
> fluctuate from year to year with the money price of corn, but
> seems to be everywhere accommodated, not to the temporary or
> occasional, but to the average or ordinary price of that necessary
> of life.

What does he mean by "money price of labor"? Why did he say it's accommodated with average "price of that necessary of life"?

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/ may be more equipped to answer this question, since it is about the interpretation of technical economic terms in the context of Adam Smith's understanding, rather than about his book considered as a literary work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does he mean by "money price of labor"?

Salaries, i.e. the price you have to pay to get someone to perform labor for you.

> Why did he say it's accommodated with average "price of that necessary of life"?

That's statement that most people today would consider a truism: Salaries are tied to the average cost of living.

Translating the paragraph to modern "plain English" and adding some explanations yields:

"The value of agricultural products changes less in the long term than the value of money does (due to inflation), but it can change a lot in the short term (due to bad or good harvests). Salaries, as I will try to show later, do not change in the short term like food prices do, but seem to be tied everywhere not to the temporary, but to the average or typical cost of living."